# Eclipse and the g++ - how is it work

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, g++

I am using ubuntu 12.04.
I have eclipse juno.
I wrote test.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

I enter to the terminal and I succeeded to run it.
The same file in eclipse I was also able to run but eclipse always warn about errors regarding the lines (red errors).

Why is it happening ?
How can I fix it ?
Why is it tells me :
cout can not be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You must have not included some include directories required to correctly parse iostream.

- Right Click on the project name.
- Select **Index** > **Search For Unresolved Includes**.

  It will give you the list of unresolved includes which you can search in `/usr/include` and add the containing directories to `C++ Include Paths and Symbols` in Project Properties.

  On my computer, I have the following directories included:

  [image]
- Rebuild the index (`Index -> Rebuild`) after adding include directories.

***Source:*** *https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804034/1626345*